# access an element of a dynamically loaded html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 HTML pages, each of them contains its jquery script. The A.html is a sliding right-docked container, its jquery file contains all the functions necessary to manage the container. The B.html contains list of messages, that should be displayed (they could be a lot), its jquery file manage all functionality of the list. For example, the list allows to scroll in order to see all messages.
I need to load the B.html file into the A.html, and then, to be able to scroll the list in B.html file, when I scroll the menu element in A.html

A.html file:

```
<div id="menu"> 
    <a href="javascript:;" class="close"></a>

    <div id="list"></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#list").load("B.html"); 

         $('#menu').scroll(function(){
            //need to call the scrolling function of b.HTML file
        });

    });
</script>
```

B.html file:

```
   <script type=text/javascript>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            return $(this).scroll(function() {
              scrollfunction();
            });

       function scrollfunction(){
           //Perform actions ...
       }
   </script>
```

**How can I do it?**

PS. I want to leave separated files in order to reuse the A.html for other scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the success callback of `load()` so that you call your new code after the new html has been inserted

```
$("#list").load("B.html", function(){
   /* new html exists now , do what is needed to it here*/

));
```

Comment: Can i call also a function of the script file in B.html like the scrollfunction() ? (Sorry but i can't test it now...).Another question: doing load() of the B.html is the same as if i would copied and pasted the entire B.html in the A.html, is it correct ?

Comment: yes, one thing to know though is that `document.ready` has already occured in main page so if scripts in loaded page are before the html they represent they won't work because they fire before the html exists